# Can't Get Basic Chef Scenario Working On Windows With Cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, windows-server

Installed Chef client and DK on a Windows Server, trying to use a recipe with a Windows feature in local mode

Ran the following

```
C:\chef>mkdir cookbooks
C:\chef>cd cookbooks
C:\chef\cookbooks>chef generate cookbook test_chef
```

Put the following in C:\chef\cookbooks\test_chef\Berksfile

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

metadata
cookbook 'windows', '~> 1.39.2'
```

Put the following in C:\chef\cookbooks\test_chef\recipes\default.rb

```
windows_feature "NetFx3" do
  action :install
  all true
end
```

ran the following

```
C:\chef\cookbooks\test_chef>berks vendor install
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'test_chef' from source at .
Using chef_handler (1.3.0)
Using test_chef (0.1.0) from source at .
Using windows (1.39.2)
Vendoring chef_handler (1.3.0) to install/chef_handler
Vendoring test_chef (0.1.0) to install/test_chef
Vendoring windows (1.39.2) to install/windows

C:\chef\cookbooks\test_chef>chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[test_chef]
[2016-04-16T04:44:06+00:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
Starting Chef Client, version 12.8.1
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["test_chef"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - test_chef (0.1.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
←[0m
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in C:/Users/admin/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test_chef/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
No resource or method named `windows_feature' for `Chef::Recipe "default"'

←[0m
Running handlers:
[2016-04-16T04:44:10+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-04-16T04:44:10+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 03 seconds
[2016-04-16T04:44:10+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to C:/Users/admin/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-04-16T04:44:10+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-04-16T04:44:10+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: No resource or method named `windows_feature' for `Chef::Recipe "defau
lt"'
```

So, even though I'm using berks vendor install and it's successfully downloading the windows cookbook to the cookbooks folder, the chef client still bombs out trying to use windows_feature.

I'm basically following an online example verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the following line to your `Berksfile`

```
cookbook 'windows', '~> 1.39.2'
```

add this line to your `metadata.rb`:

```
depends 'windows', '~> 1.39.2'
```

Berkshelf will still be able to download this dependency from the supermarket (as it is added as `source`), but not also `chef-client` will load the *windows* cookbook prior to your cookbook and thus the `windows_feature` resource will be known.

Comment: what's the actual difference this makes?

Comment: Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: windows

Comment: do i still need the berksfile or something?

Comment: so I did berks vendor cookbooks, then chef-client, now I get uninitialized constant Chef::Provider::WindowsFeature::ServerManagerCmd

Comment: As said, Berkshelf will download the cookbook from the defined source (i.e. Chef supermarket). This incorporates the dependencies of the cookbook as specified in `metadata.rb`. When executing `chef-client`, it will load all cookbooks' resources during the compile phase of the chef run, thus make them available to all cookbooks. That's why you need to specify it as dependency in `metadata.rb`.

Comment: It will download the dependency so long as your berksfile contains a `source` attribute it can be found at, i.e. having this line at the start of your berksfile `source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'`. The next piece is making berks aware of your metadata by adding the line `metadata` to the end of your berksfile.